# What do these lines of code mean?

Tags: jquery

I have extracxted the code below from a plugin and Im struggling to understand certain lines of code like the extend,insertAfter and append methods used here.I didnt want copy and paste the whole code so I have made some changes,hope it doesnt confuse you guys?Would someone please explain these line of code

```
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();    
    $j("#myDiv").myPlugin({

                    ready: function() {
                        someFunction_1();
                    },
                    change: function(isOn) {
                        someFunction_2();           
                    }
                });


        $j.fn.myPlugin = function(arg) {

             if (typeof(arg) == "undefined" || typeof(arg) == "object") {

                this.hide().each(function() {

                     var data = $j.extend({ checkbox: $j(this), cancelClick: false }, typeof(arg) == "object" ? arg : { });

                     data.div = $j("<div class='slider-switch-actual'></div>").insertAfter($j(this).data("sliderSwitch", data));


                      data.div.append(


                        $j("<img/>")
                            .attr("src", "image.png")
                            .addClass("active")
                            .load(function() {
                            //code

                            });
)
                }
            }


            return this;
            }
```

Comment: This is a bit much to explain IMO. Which part are you confused about? What is your situation with all this?

Comment: I suggest you start by reading http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: i think using a search engine such as google would be more useful and comprehensive, save you time and save us time, when trying to learn about basic functions of jquery.

Comment: @pekka thanks for you comments, i mainly wanted to know what data.div.append() method would do. div is a object,div:{0:{ },length: 1}.I know how a basic apend method works in jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery.extend: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

jQuery.insertAfter: http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

jQuery.append: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

Some people have already explained all this... in the documentation of jQuery:

[jQuery.extend()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

[.insertAfter()](https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)

[.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)